# filling in one cell with a reference number will auto populate the next 5 cells with data from a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I use Excel alot in my work and have to manually add in information from another spreadsheet some times 20 times sometimes 900 times depending on the building I am surveying.

I would like to automate this if possible.

For me each asset in a building has a specification number and a corresponding amount of time per frequency the maintenance is required.

So if the code is say 03-01 there maybe a weekly visit of .08 (min n decimal) a 6 monthly visit of .25 and an annual of 1

[Weekly][Monthly][Quartlery][6Monthly][Annual]

And there could be say 1000 rows of this data

01-01
down to 
100-01

for example

On my main spreadsheet I would like to put into 1 cell the reference number that goes with the asset item.  Say an AHU is 03-01 then when I type in 03-01 in 1 cell, excel looks up on the table for 03-01 and then uses the information in the next 5 cells and autopopulates that information into my 1st spreadsheet.

If that makes sence?

Would save me SO MUCH TIME

example data

```
       [Weekly][Monthly][Quartlery][6Monthly][Annual]
```

1. [01-01]  [  .08]    [  0 ]    [   .25 ]    [    0 ]    [    1]
2. [01-02]  [  .04]    [  0 ]    [   0   ]    [   0  ]    [   0]
3. [01-03]  [   0 ]    [  0 ]    [   .25 ]    [    0 ]    [    0]
4. [01-04]  [   0 ]    [  0 ]    [   0   ]    [   0  ]    [ 1.5 ]
5. [01-05]  [   0 ]    [  0 ]    [   .25 ]    [    0 ]    [   0 ]

Example spreadsheet

Asset     CODE         [Weekly][Monthly][Quartlery][6Monthly][Annual]

```
    Man input
```

AHU      [03-01]       [          Autopopulates this row            ]

Then onto the next line for as many lines as nessessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily done with a `VLOOKUP()` formula...

I have assumed your raw-data is in cells `A2` to `F6` and have made the formulas work for cells `A15` to `F19`.

[image: Example]

The formula you need in `B15` is:

```
=VLOOKUP($A15;$A$2:$F$6;2;FALSE)
```

You can copy the formula to `C15`, `D15`, `E15` and `F15`. You then input your "Asset CODE" in cell `A15` all other cells populate automatically. Repeat for as many lines as you need.

You can combine this with an `IF()` statement if needed.